# Quelle est la définition de « fuséonautique » et est-ce synonyme de « fuséologie » etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, synonymes, science, suffixes

Un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/sciences/2022-08-03/polytechnique-montreal/des-prototypes-quebecois-recompenses-sur-la-scene-internationale.php) parle d'une compétition de *fuséonautique*. Le TLFi discute de l'élément formant [-nautique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-nautique) servant à élaborer des « substantifs féminins indiquant la science ou la technique qui a pour objet la navigation dont le type est indiqué par le 1er élément du substantif » (TLFi) ; [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=FUSEONAUTIQUE) utilise *fuséonautique* au même titre que *fuséologie* pour traduire *rocketry*, et s'appuie sur une version du Petit Robert pour la deuxième la définissant comme la « science et technique des fusées en tant que telles, indépendamment de l'astronautique et de l'aéronautique » alors que le [GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/19471948/fuseonautique) ne définit pas non plus la *fuséonautique*.

- Quelle est la définition du substantif « fuséonautique » ?
- La fuséonautique et la fuséologie sont-ils synonymes ; la différence
  est-elle du même ordre que pour *cosmonautique* et *cosmologie*, le
  premier étant aussi un adjectif basé sur un substantif (*cosmonaute*)
  ?
- Les termes plus récents dans ce genre de domaine sont-ils plus
  souvent formés avec -nautique ; s'agit-il d'une question de
  productivité des éléments formants respectifs ([*-logie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-logie),
  *-nautique*) ou est-ce l'aspect « relatif à la navigation » qui est déterminant dans la formation des termes, et dans la compétition de
  l'article pouvait-il s'agir d'une « compétition de fuséologie » dans
  le sens où faire monter une fusée à la verticale est-il « relatif à
  la navigation » ?

Answer (score 3):

Je ne connaissais pas *fuséonautique* et je suis assez perplexe sur sa construction.

De l'argonaute grec, on a tiré un certain nombre de mots en -naute pour représenter des navigateurs se déplaçant dans un milieu donné :

air → aéronaute
océan → océanaute (rare)
astres → astronaute  (américains)
espace → spationaute  (européens)
cosmos → cosmonaute  (russes)
*taìkōng* → taikonautes (rare, chinois)

On peut ajouter à cette liste ceux qui naviguent sur Internet, les internautes.

Deux d'entre eux seulement ont donné des dérivés à l'usage établi, aéronautique et astronautique. Le premier s'intéresse à l'étude des "navires" se déplaçant dans l'atmosphère, le deuxième à ceux qui vont au-delà de cette dernière.

Les fusées n'étant que des engins se déplaçant dans l'atmosphère et parfois au-delà, leur étude fait au sens large partie des l'aéronautique ou de l'astronautique.

La spécialisation de cette étude, en particulier plus récemment par des amateurs s'intéressant à des engins non destinés au transport de personnes, a été parfois désignée sous les mots *fuséonautique* et *fuséologie*. On trouve *fuséonautique* dans des documents français de la fin des années cinquante, le mot n'est donc pas un québécisme même si aujourd'hui, on le trouve surtout employé au Canada francophone.

Exemple :

> La Conquête de l’Espace par la Puissance Fuséonautique et la Domination Nouvelle de la Terre & Partir de l’Air; le Satellite Naturel ou Artificiel et son Canal Aérien. Edouard B.- Winandy. (Congres Internatl. Fusées & Engins- Guidés, Paris, Dec. 3-8, 1956.)

*Fuséonautique* ne correspond pas sémantiquement aux autres mots de même construction car d'une part, il n'y a pas de pilote ou de passagers embarqués (pas de *fuséonaute*) et d'autre part, le milieu traversé par l'engin n'est pas la fusée elle-même, on confond le navire et la mer.

*Fuséologie* est plus logique. On a des *fuséologues* qui étudient les fusées, science qui se nomme la *fuséologie* comme l'étude des océans donne *océanologue/logie* ou l'étude des volcans *volcanologue/logie*. C'est peut-être la proximité avec *astrologue/logie* ou *ufologue/ufologie* qui ne font pas forcément sérieux dans un univers scientifique qui a encouragé l'essor de l'étrange *fuséonautique*.

Comment: J'ai remarqué qu'au TLFi, l'explication de la création des substantifs pour le domaine escamote le passage par le substantif pour la personne c-à-d. que fuséonautique ne passe pas par fuséonaute tel que tu l'observes, comme cosmonaute pour cosmonautique par exemple. Eux ils voyaient ces cas-là (cosmonautique) comme des adjectifs. Oui j'ai pensé à l'argument du _sérieux_ de la chose. Mais je me demande si les nouveaux termes vont plus avoir recours à -nautique, peut-être finalement par émulation de -ics en anglais (robotics etc.). Ou on va utiliser ça quand il n'y a pas de « pilote ».

Comment: @Personne Merci, une petite erreur de sémiologuie... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Cela vient peut être du Québec ou j’ai trouvé une définition de fuseonautique :

> science concernant la construction et le lancement d'aéronefs expérimentaux propulsés par des moteurs à carburant de fusée puissants, rapides et potentiellement dangeureux

Ref [ClubQF](http://clubqf.ca/info-medias.html)

Comment: Penses-tu qu'ils utilisent ça comme synonyme de _fuséologie_ ou en d'autres termes comment cette définition diffère-t-elle de celle de _fuséologie_ ?

Comment: Ça me semble plus restrictif que la fuseologie. Cela correspond plus à des expériences (d’amateurs ?) plus qu’à une étude scientifique. Peut-être le côté pratique. Je pense aussi peut-être un terme québécois.

Comment: Je suis pas certain mais [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2source?lang=eng&srchtxt=FUSEONAUTIQUE&i=1&index=alt&src_id=PEROB-WWW2018&rlang=fr&titl=fus%C3%A9onautique&fchrcrdnm=1#resultrecs) semble dire que c'est dans le Nouveau Petit Robert... mais ces dictionnaires ajoutent aussi des termes provenant du Québec.

Comment: Je ne l’ai pas trouvé sur le  [Robert en ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/) ou dans [France Terme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme)